# Make an android music streaming app so that the song is not downloadable

Tags: android, download, stream, drm

I am developing an android app for a music label. They have their own server. I fetch json responses and stream the songs. I want to know that is there any way for the USERS to use 3rd-party softwares and download those songs.

There are questions on how to download songs using stream links. That I can do. But my question is different.

Answer (score 1):

When you stream music from server it get buffered in your RAM. If you want to make the songs not downloadable you can add extra security like app_keys while communicating with server. I think no one will be able to download the song until unless its a getting streamed from public API.

For extra level of security clear the buffered data whenever user leaves the screen.

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() is faster. It prepares the player asynchronously (faster!).

I am using app_keys and stuff. So i guess I am covered from the security side. Thanks for your opinion!   :)